# AUTO_INCREMENT primary key and update its references in other tables at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a main student table and multiple other tables that contain student_id reference in them. I need to change `student_id` (which is a primary key) in the main student table by

```
ALTER TABLE `student` AUTO_INCREMENT = 72805;
```

And replace all student_id references in all tables (including main student table) starting with `72805`. Is there any way to do this?

**student table**

```
student_id   student_name
    1           Sarah
    2           John
    3           Peter
```

**class table**

```
class_id    student_id
        340         2
        432         1
        127         3
```

**activity**

```
activity_id     student_id
    105             1
    106             1
    205             2
    207             2
    217             3
```

**books table**

```
boook_id    student_id
    105         1
    106         1
    205         2
    207         2
    217         3
```

Comment: Are the keys using `ON UPDATE CASCADE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the foreign key constraints on Class, Activity and Books and recreate them with an ON UPDATE CASCADE clause.

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE class;
SHOW CREATE TABLE activity;
SHOW CREATE TABLE books;
```

These will show you the names of the foreign key constraints. You'll need the name of the foreign key constraint on `student_id`.

```
ALTER TABLE class DROP FOREIGN KEY [enter the foreign key name here], ADD CONSTRAINT [enter foreign key name here] FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES student (`student_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE activity DROP FOREIGN KEY [enter the foreign key name here], ADD CONSTRAINT [enter foreign key name here] FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES student (`student_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE books DROP FOREIGN KEY [enter the foreign key name here], ADD CONSTRAINT [enter foreign key name here] FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES student (`student_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Doing this tells MySQL that if you update the student_id on the student table to update the value in the referencing tables. Depending on your business logic depends on whether you keep the ON UPDATE CASCADE clause. I never personally use it because it's rare you update a primary key.
If you don't have foreign keys, then you should remove the drop clause and keep the add clause.

The structure is in place to now update your student_id and have it cascade to the other tables.

```
UPDATE student SET student_id = student_id + 72804; -- Minus 1 because the values already in here start at 1, not 0.
```

You don't want to set the auto_increment to 72805, because that's where you want the first record to *start* from and you now have a row occupying that value.
This query will get you the value you should now set the auto_increment value to.

```
SELECT MAX(student_id) + 1 FROM student;
```

Now run your ALTER table statement and set the auto_increment to the value you received from the above query.

```
ALTER TABLE student AUTO_INCREMENT = [Value you receive from the SELECT MAX()].
```

When that's done, I would drop and recreate the foreign keys *without* the ON UPDATE CASCADE.

```
ALTER TABLE class DROP FOREIGN KEY [enter the foreign key name here], ADD CONSTRAINT [enter foreign key name here] FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES student (`student_id`);
ALTER TABLE activity DROP FOREIGN KEY [enter the foreign key name here], ADD CONSTRAINT [enter foreign key name here] FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES student (`student_id`);
ALTER TABLE books DROP FOREIGN KEY [enter the foreign key name here], ADD CONSTRAINT [enter foreign key name here] FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES student (`student_id`);
```

Comment: Worked beautifully! Thank you